# I want to send email to user from API response in Javascript/ Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm using a google apps script to get data from an external API. I was wondering if there is a way I can get the data from JSON sent to a user email on G-suite/Gmail after below code is executed. Anyone with ana idea on how to do this?

```
  var url = 'https....';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  var id = json["id"];
  sheet.getRange(2+i, 21).setValue(id);
  sheet.getRange(2+i, 22).setValue(1);
  }
else {
 sheet.getRange(2+i, 22).setValue(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of both sendEmail functions, depending if you want the json to simply be in the body [1] or as an attached file [2]. A simple example would be:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("mike@example.com", "current time", "The time is:");
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options

Comment: Thanks, @Andres. This was very helpful.